# GECKO - I need to send a TAB or lose focus after the field is filled

Tags: c#, gecko

Please, I need to send a TAB or lose focus after the field is filled. Is it possible?
See the example below in the comment position:

```
private bool SetTextoInput_NAME(string NAME, string strValue)
{
    GeckoElementCollection ele = oGecko.Document.GetElementsByName(NAME);

    try
    {
        if (ele == null) return false;

        foreach (var item in ele)
        {
            if (item.GetType().ToString() == "Gecko.DOM.GeckoInputElement")
            {
                ((GeckoInputElement)item).Value = strValue;
                // I NEED TO SEND A "TAB" AFTER THE FIELD FILLED...
                // SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```